# Android Marge two .wav file into one file

Tags: android, cordova-plugins, wav, ionic-native

Hi am not an Android Developer but I am a hybrid app developer. I have knowledge about how can create the Cordova plugin.

I want to create a plugin to merge two .wav file in Java Android. 
Could you please send me any example code (Java Android) on how to merge two .wav files.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi Sohan and welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Search in SO. There are a lot of information about how to concatenate two wav files.

Answer (score 1):

use SequenceInputStream like this:

```
appendedFiles = 
                new AudioInputStream(
                        new SequenceInputStream(clip1, clip2),
                        clip1.getFormat(),
                        clip1.getFrameLength() + clip2.getFrameLength()
                        );
```